# How to destructure a JSON object containing two objects into an array?

Tags: javascript, json, destructuring

[image: Screenshot of console]

I have a JSON object, color, that consists of two JSON objects. I need to transfer these two JSON objects to an array. How can I do that?

i.e. {blue, purple} to [blue, purple]

Comment: is it alway blue and purple as property?

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes

Comment: why not use just the properties?

Comment: Are you just looking for `[colors.blue, colors.purple]`?

Comment: I need to be able to .map through the array.

Comment: Do you need the array beyond that?  Could you not `Object.keys(color).map(...)` and achieve what you want without the transform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The need for this is probably a code smell, but here you go:

```
const colorObject = {
  blue: { "foo": "bar" },
  purple: { "baz": "qum" }
};

const colorArray = Object.keys(colorObject).map(k => colorObject[k]);

console.log(colorArray);
```

As James Thorpe mentions in the comment above, if you can do this once without keeping the array around, that's preferable.

Comment: You dont need a `push` within a `map` - it'll do that all by itself with `.map(k => colorObject[k])`

Answer (score 1):

## Solution

```js
let obj = {blue: {foo: 'bar'}, purple: {baz: 'qux'}};

let arr = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);

console.log(arr);
```